# Как в ItemsControl Avalonia C# добраться до выделенного в данный момент элемента?

Tags: c#, avalonia, itemscontrol

Имеется ItemsControl, каждый элемент которого определён как TextBox

```
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding TrainingsList}" Width="300" Height="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Как в ItemsControl добраться до выделенного в данный момент элемента? У ItemsControl нет свойства SelectedItem или SelectedIndex как у ComboBox.

Comment: Нужно выделение, используйте `ListBox`, он для этого и создан. Задача `ItemsControl` только вывести последовательно объекты на экран, не более. Ну а там уже "связывайте" выделение с фокусом `TextBox`. Ну... Либо пишите свои костыли, где у вас в классе будет не только `Name`, но еще и `bool` свойство, которое будет привязано к выделению `TextBox`, тогда уже делайте в коде `TrainingsList.Where(x=>x.Свойство)` (если нужен один, то `FirstOrDefault(аналогично)`).